# How to get Recently Played songs Playlist with the help of MediaStore in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, playlist, mediastore

How to get songs from Recently Played , Recentyly Added, Top Played...Playlist with the help of MediaStore in android..
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The standard android database does not offer any fields for this.  You can find the tables in. /Data/data/com.android.provider.com.media. you will need root .

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of the frequently played tracks or recently added , you would have to apply logic for it and will have to create a database for your application since android keeps no track of them and thus, these all are application specific things which must be handled by user application alone.